# when password will be encrypted while logging in?

Tags: authentication, proxy, password-encryption, zap

While logging into a webpage (for example gmail), at which point those credentials will be encrypted??

In my case:
Actually I have used ZAP proxy to analyze traffic going through my browser.
When I login to gmail and analyzing the traffic through ZAP proxy, I am able to see the password in plain text format.

So when was encryption happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since gmail uses SSL, the entire request, password and all, is encrypted by the browser.

That being said, the question is then, how am I able to see the plaintext when using zap?  Zaproxy intercepts the SSL handshake and establishes it's own connection with Gmail. It then uses a different certificate to communicate with your browser.

This allows you to view the request/response in plaintext because proxy has access to it.

Comment: so as per my understanding on above answer, ZAP acts kind of like **MITM** (_man in the middle_). ZAP establishes a **http** connection with browser and **https(SSL)** connection with Gmail server. So Gmail doesn't have any script to encrypt password before sending. Is it completely relying on SSL? correct me if I'm wrong @Chet

Comment: Well, the browser establishes a secure https session with zap (it just doesn't realize it, because zap used a certificate that it installed). There is no http involved. Other than that, you are exactly correct.